# Uploading and labeling pairs of photos

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I created a ResNet18 to detect if 2 individuals are siblings or not, by giving an image of each one (the model has input_size = 2).
I need to create my dataset, in which I will specify which pair are siblings or not.

I tried:

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('training',
                                                 target_size=(28,28),
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='binary')
```

And I got training_set.classes `array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])`

for training_set.filenames

```
 'false\\false1\\_DSC5763.jpg',
 'false\\false2\\_DSC5751.jpg',
 'false\\false2\\_DSC5760.jpg',
 'siblings\\siblings1\\_DSC5751.jpg',
 'siblings\\siblings1\\_DSC5755_1.jpg',
 'siblings\\siblings2\\_DSC5760.jpg',
 'siblings\\siblings2\\_DSC5763.jpg'
```

The training_set.classes should be `array([0, 0, 1, 1])`, for my purposes.
How can I do this?

Comment: How does your data look like for false pairs, do you have a pair of images which are labelled as not sibling? or do you have just pairs of siblings and any other random pair implies not-sibling?

Comment: Again, to confirm do you have negative cases? I.e. do you have something like `person1 person2 not_sibling`. Or just the positive cases, i.e. all rows contains pairs of people who are actually siblings.

Comment: I have a picture for 180 individuals and an excel file which tells what pairs are siblings or not.  This is how the header and a row of the excel file looks like:                                         
.................................................................. ```unique ID;  siblings?; first picture; second picture;                                                              0003_0001     1            3/DSC5751  1/DSC5755_1```

Comment: So, what am I asking is do you have entries where `siblings?` is `0`?

Comment: Yes, I have where siblings are 0

Answer (score 0):

I finished my project and I thought to come back to post the answer I found. I am trying to classify if 2 individuals are siblings or not.

```
#Lists used for creating the dataset
categories = []
first_img= []
second_img = []

#Parsing throw the images and making 2 arrays
for filename in filenames:
    category = filename.split('.')[0]

    #Each pair is named <sibling/false>+<nr_of_pair>+0/1
    if 'sibling' in category:
        if filename.split('_')[1][0] == '0':
            first_img.append(filename)
            categories.append(1)
        else:
            second_img.append(filename)
    else:
        if filename.split('_')[1][0] == '0':
            first_img.append(filename)
            categories.append(0)
        else:
            second_img.append(filename)

#dataset of the first individual of the pair and it's label      
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'filename': first_img,
    'category': categories
}).astype('str')

#dataset of the second individual of the pair and it's label  
df2 =pd.DataFrame({
    'filename': second_img,
    'category': categories
}).astype('str')
```

And for the fit_generator I used the function.

```
def generate_generator_multiple(datagen):
    train_generator1 = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df1, 
                                                        "../train/input/", 
                                                        x_col='filename',
                                                        y_col='category',
                                                        class_mode='binary',
                                                        target_size=(image_size1, image_size2),
                                                        batch_size = batch_size)

    train_generator2 = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df2, 
                                                        "../train/input/", 
                                                        x_col='filename',
                                                        y_col='category',
                                                        class_mode='binary',
                                                        target_size=(image_size1, image_size2),
                                                        batch_size = batch_size)
    while True:
            X1i = train_generator1.next()
            X2i = train_generator2.next()
            yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]  #Yield both images and their mutual
```

datagen is a ImageDataGenerator object